# Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, validation, jpa

**First of all sorry for my language, english is not my mother language**

*Any help will be appreciated*

I'm trying to develop basic Spring Boot application with JPA.I have finished the most of the project, and project include form validation as well.Whenever I try to add new Person it's working well and I can get correct validate message from the valitador, also, I can update the person without any problem but whenever I make mistake the update form, the validator causes this error

Error

```
Wed May 20 18:49:01 EET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:543)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:712)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at sen3004.app6.service.App6Service$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88491962.update(<generated>)
    at sen3004.app6.web.App6Controller.update(App6Controller.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [sen3004.app6.model.Person] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='boyut '3' ile '50' arasında olmalı', propertyPath=firstName, rootBeanClass=class sen3004.app6.model.Person, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1344)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3221)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2389)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    ... 65 more
```

I looked at some solutions on the internet but it didn't work for me.Here the working valitador in add new person

[image: Add New Person]

I need the fix the problem and it should give me the same errors when I try to update the person (with mistakes)

Here is my controller

```
package sen3004.app6.web;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import sen3004.app6.model.Person;
import sen3004.app6.service.App6Service;

@Controller
public class App6Controller {

    @Autowired
    App6Service service;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "index.html"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndex() {
        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = {"/display-form", "create.html"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("form");
        mv.addObject("person", new Person());

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute Person person, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject("person", person);

        if (result.hasErrors())
            mv.setViewName("form");
        else {
            mv.setViewName("result");
            service.create(person);
            mv.addObject("people", service.findAll());
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/list-people", "list.html"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView list() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("result");
        mv.addObject("people", service.findAll());

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/edit/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editList(@PathVariable long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("update");
        mv.addObject("person", service.findById(id));
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update(@Valid @ModelAttribute Person person,
                               BindingResult result,
                               @PathVariable long id
                               ) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            person.setId(id);
            mv.setViewName("update");
        }
        service.update(person);
        mv.addObject("people", service.findAll());
        mv.setViewName("result");


        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("result");
        service.delete(id);
        mv.addObject("people", service.findAll());

        return mv;
    }

}
```

Here is my IPerson class and service Class

```
IPerson.java

package sen3004.app6.service;

import java.util.List;

import sen3004.app6.model.Person;

public interface IPerson {
    public List<Person> findAll();

    public Person findById(long id);

    public void create(Person person);

    public void delete(long id);

    public void update(Person person);

}
```

App6Service.java

```
package sen3004.app6.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import sen3004.app6.dao.App6Repository;
import sen3004.app6.model.Person;

@Service
@Transactional
public class App6Service implements IPerson {

    @Autowired
    App6Repository repository;

    @Override
    public List<Person> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Person findById(long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(Person person) {
        repository.create(person);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        repository.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Person person) {
        repository.update(person);
    }

}
```

App6Repository.java

```
package sen3004.app6.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import sen3004.app6.model.Person;
import sen3004.app6.service.IPerson;

@Repository
public class App6Repository implements IPerson {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Person> findAll(){
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Person", Person.class).getResultList();
    }

    public Person findById(long id){
        return entityManager.find(Person.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Person person) {
        entityManager.merge(person);

    }

    @Override
    public void create(Person person) {
        entityManager.persist(person); 
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(Person.class, id));
    } 
}
```

Model
Person.java

```
package sen3004.app6.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String firstName;
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "lname")
    private String lastName;
    @Past
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    @Column(name = "dob")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    @Min(value = 12)
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;
    @Email
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9\\s]{12}")
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

app6application.java

```
package sen3004.app6;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App6Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App6Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

messages.properties

```
Size.person.firstName=Value must contain at least 3, at most 50 characters.
Size.person.lastName=Value must contain at least 3, at most 50 characters.
Past.person.dateOfBirth=Value must be a past date.
typeMismatch.person.dateOfBirth=Value must be a valid date (dd-mm-yyyy).
Min.person.age=Our patients must have completed the age of 12 as per the age policy!
Email.person.email=You must give valid Email!
Pattern.person.phone=Phone number that given is invalid! For ex.: 9053839052094
greeting=Hello! Welcome to Our Site!
lang.change=Change The Language
lang.eng=English
lang.tr=Turkish
msg.addperson =Add Person
msg.firstname=First Name
msg.lastname=Last Name
msg.dateOfBirth=Date Of Birth
msg.age=Age
msg.email=Email
msg.phone=Phone
msg.persons=Persons
msg.noperson=No Person Found!
msg.id=ID
msg.updateperson=Update Person
```

update.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><s:message code="msg.updateperson"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container my-5">
    <h3><s:message code="msg.updateperson"/></h3>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form:form method="post" action="/update/${person.id}" modelAttribute="person">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="firstName" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.firstname"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="firstName"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="lastName" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.lastname"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="lastName"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dateOfBirth" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.dateOfBirth"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" id="dateOfBirth"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="dateOfBirth"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="age" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.age"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="age" class="form-control" id="age"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="age"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="email" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.email"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="email" class="form-control" id="email"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="email"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.phone"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="phone" class="form-control" id="phone"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="phone"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
                <p>You can view a list of existing people <a href="/list.html">here</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

form.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><s:message code="msg.addperson"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container my-5">
    <h3><s:message code="msg.addperson"/></h3>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form:form method="post" action="/send" modelAttribute="person">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="firstName" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.firstname"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="firstName" class="form-control" id="firstName"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="firstName"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="lastName" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.lastname"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="lastName" class="form-control" id="lastName"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="lastName"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="dateOfBirth" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.dateOfBirth"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" id="dateOfBirth"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="dateOfBirth"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="age" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.age"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="age" class="form-control" id="age"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="age"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="email" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.email"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="email" class="form-control" id="email"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="email"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-form-label"><s:message code="msg.phone"/></label>
                            <sf:input path="phone" class="form-control" id="phone"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><form:errors path="phone"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
                <p>You can view a list of existing people <a href="/list.html">here</a>.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

info.app.name=App6
info.app.desc=Spring Boot and JPA

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/sql/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/sql/data.sql

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: in your log you can see the constraint that throw the exception   `ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='boyut '3' ile '50' arasında olmalı', propertyPath=firstName, rootBeanClass=class sen3004.app6.model.Person, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'} `   Could you give the exact data that you put to create the person (firstname, lastname, ..)

Comment: I didn't understand but if I give the correct data, the update function work without problem

Answer (score 4):

Could you change the method

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update(@Valid @ModelAttribute Person person,
        BindingResult result,
        @PathVariable long id
        ) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            person.setId(id);
            mv.setViewName("update");
        }
        service.update(person);
        mv.addObject("people", service.findAll());
        mv.setViewName("result");


        return mv;
    }
}
```

with this

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView update(@Valid @ModelAttribute Person person,
        BindingResult result,
        @PathVariable long id
        ) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            person.setId(id);
            mv.setViewName("update");
            return mv; // ADD THIS RETURN HERE.
        }
        service.update(person);
        mv.addObject("people", service.findAll());
        mv.setViewName("result");


        return mv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the shared code snippets in App6Controller, in the method update, no condition is checked during update operation validation error, hence error thrown by hibernate validator during save operation.  Carry out update operation if no errors.